# Installation Error with 2018.3.3 Desktop Tableau on 64bit Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-installation, tableau

Assistance needed with 2018.3.3 Desktop Tableau 64 bit install on Windows 10 x64 laptop. How to reproduce the problem:

1. Right click on TableauDesktop-64bit-2018-3-3.exe and select "Run as Administrator"
2. Installer starts humming with nice gui representation of progress
3. Nice dialog box appears and displays the following:

[image]

I know I have no existing installation on this laptop (2x check Programs in the Control Panel...nothing).

Check log file and see this:

```
[28F4:39B0][2019-02-01T09:53:06]e000: Error 0x80070666: Process returned error: 0x666
[28F4:39B0][2019-02-01T09:53:06]e000: Error 0x80070666: Failed to execute EXE package.
[3E54:3E58][2019-02-01T09:53:06]e000: Error 0x80070666: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[3E54:3E58][2019-02-01T09:53:06]i319: Applied execute package: VC2017Redist, result: 0x80070666, restart: None
[3E54:3E58][2019-02-01T09:53:06]e000: Error 0x80070666: Failed to execute EXE package.
[28F4:39B0][2019-02-01T09:53:06]i351: Removing cached package: VC2017Redist, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\48E3744F33F49113BE971E334754F1E475C5AFAA\
```

Surmise that it detects existing installation of the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (X64) 14.16.27012".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Log Files Indicate Detection of the Installation of "Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (X64) 14.16.27012" which Leads Installer to Throw Error and Shutdown Installation**

Solution:

1. Navigate to `control panel>Programs and Features`
2. Observe installation of "Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (X64) 14.16.27012"
3. Consider dependent program associated with the "Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (X64) 14.16.27012". Make notes of this uninstall because it could affect a dependent program. In this case, the installation date with about a month ago at about the same time that Visual Studio itself was installed with no other known dependent programs (might need to uninstall, reinstall). I do not use Visual Studio very often (and might need to uninstall/reinstall it).
4. Proceed to uninstall "Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (X64) 14.16.27012"
5. Right click on TableauDesktop-64bit-2018-3-3.exe and select "Run as Administrator"
6. Watch installer start humming with nice gui representation of progress
7. Smile when the install completes successfully

Comment: Also helped me install Tableau Public 2020, removed VC++ 2017 14.16. * slightly different version.